# Suspend/Resume restarts the machine (GNOME)

Tags: date-time, gnome3, debian-bullseye

2023-05-19 GNOME "Power Off/Log Out -> Suspend" restarted the machine three times in a row. I was trying to suspend the machine from the lock screen (before logging in). Usually this restart happens rare, once in say three days. Ditto after suspend/resume the system time is off. Two or three days. I used to run

```
$ systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd.service
```

to fix the time. Another thing. Before suspending I run $ sudo sync. Sometimes after the resume sudo doesn't ask the password even if the resume happens 10 hours after.

Using:

AMD A6-5400K APU with Radeon Version E7792AMS V2.2.
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) with the latest updates
GNOME Version 3.38.5

**UPDATE 2023-05-26**

At 0:00 AM 2023-05-26 Power Off/Log Out > Suspend restarted the machine

**UPDATE 2023-06-09**

GNOME Suspend restarted the machine with all updates being installed

Comment: Try to upgrade to the latest kernel version.

Comment: Installed. I missed it, guess it was quite recent.

Comment: The update fixed the problem

Comment: I added an answer, please consider accepting it. An upvote would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest kernel version has fixed the problem.

Suspend/Resume now works correctly.

Comment: The upgrade definitely fixed the problem I described. Yet, the time after resume often is off (days). I experience that for a very long time (reported it too, another topic). Still don't know what the real cause of the problem. It was said (in discussion) that the problem might be in the hardware I'm using.

Comment: At 0:00 2023-05-26 the Suspend restarted the machine

Comment: 2023-06-09 , about 23:00 PM GNOME Suspend restarted the machine

Comment: So the problem only seemed to be fixed? See [How to find reason a notebook wakes up?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132115/how-to-find-reason-a-notebook-wakes-up)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't quite follow you. I have a stationary workstation and the problem is that the Suspend restarts the computer.

Comment: The link proposes several methods to find why a Linux computer has woken up. See if one of the methods can point to the reason why your computer wakes up.