# Restart Firefox-esr to speed up the machine

Tags: firefox, gnome3, debian-bullseye

Firefox ESR is too slow to load a site. More than 3 min to load ludwig.guru/, waited for 3 mins then killed the app.
less than 10 secs after reboot

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-howtos 53 sec before reboot.
After reboot 30 sec

I usually to not reboot the machine often, instead I use GNOME Suspend with which feature I reported problems:

[set-system-time-after-suspend](https://superuser.com/questions/1726050/set-system-time-after-suspend) 
[suspend-resume-restarts-the-machine-gnome](https://superuser.com/questions/1785000/suspend-resume-restarts-the-machine-gnome)

which might be relevant

Using:

AMD A6-5400K APU with Radeon Version E7792AMS V2.2.
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) with the latest updates
GNOME Version 3.38.5
102.12.0esr (64-bit)